# How to make the word size in the LaTeX formula become the same in the table?

Tags: latex

How to make the word size of numerator smaller?

[image: 1]

I have tried to modified the whole table' s word size, but only this formulation's numerator of word become large.

Comment: Please add a [mre]

Comment: \begin{table}[H]\footnotesize%\begin{tabular}{l|c}
\toprule[2pt]
Case & $\beta_H^*$ \\\midrule[2pt]
(1) $I$ & $p(-p-q_I+1)$\\\hline
(2) $I+H+L$ & $\frac{\splitfrac{2q_I\gamma_H(\gamma_H - \gamma_L)}{\splitfrac{-(2p\gamma_H - 2p + q_I\gamma_H)}{(3\gamma_H\gamma_L - 4\gamma_H + \gamma_L)}}}{4q_I\gamma_H(\gamma_H - \gamma_L)}$\\
\bottomrule[2pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mre], a short but compilable test document including a class, the necessary packages and everything else necessary to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

*First, please always provide the MWE!*

You can add `\scriptstyle` to each inner component of `\splitfrac` to decrease font in that three part fraction.

I also added another example of your table with the straight fraction. IMO it looks much clearer. Besides, can the first terms be reduced?

As a side note, If you add something larger than one line to `array` or `tabular` with rules, it is almost always required to provide extra vertical spacing. Otherwise, the content "hugs" both top and the bottom rules. `mathtools` provides a macro `\xmathstrut[]{}` which helps with that.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\spr}{m}{\specialrule{#1}{0pt}{0pt}}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.25}
  \DeclareDocumentCommand{\heavyrulewidth}{}{2pt}
  \DeclareDocumentCommand{\lightrulewidth}{}{2pt}
  \[
    \begin{array}{l@{\hspace{0.5em}}l|c}
      \spr{\heavyrulewidth}
      \mathrlap{Case} &       & \beta_H^{*} \\
      \spr{\lightrulewidth}
      (1)             & I     & p(-p-q_I+1) \\
      \spr{0.4pt}
      (2)             & I+H+L & \frac{
                                  \splitfrac{
                                    \scriptstyle 2q_I\gamma_H(\gamma_H - \gamma_L)
                                  }{\splitfrac{
                                      \scriptstyle -(2p\gamma_H - 2p + q_I\gamma_H)
                                    }{
                                      \scriptstyle (3\gamma_H\gamma_L - 4\gamma_H + \gamma_L)
                                    }
                                  }
                                }{4q_I\gamma_H(\gamma_H - \gamma_L)}\xmathstrut[0.75]{2.5} \\
      \spr{\heavyrulewidth}
    \end{array}
  \]
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}
  \DeclareDocumentCommand{\heavyrulewidth}{}{1.2pt}
  \DeclareDocumentCommand{\lightrulewidth}{}{0.8pt}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{-2pt}
  \[
    \begin{array}{l@{\hspace{0.5em}}l|c}
      \spr{\heavyrulewidth}
      \mathrlap{Case} &       & \beta_H^{*} \\
      \spr{\lightrulewidth}
      (1)             & I     & p(-p-q_I+1) \\
      \spr{0.4pt}
      (2)             & I+H+L & \dfrac{1}{2}
                                - \dfrac{
                                  (2p\gamma_H - 2p + q_I\gamma_H)(3\gamma_H\gamma_L - 4\gamma_H + \gamma_L)
                                }{
                                  4q_I\gamma_H(\gamma_H - \gamma_L)
                                }\xmathstrut{1.25}\\
      \spr{\heavyrulewidth}
    \end{array}
  \]
\end{table}
\end{document}
```